# ASPNET WMI class not available

Tags: iis, wmi, performance-counters

I need to extract the **ASPNET\Requests Queued** performance counter from some IIS servers via WMI.

The WMI class for this sort of thing appears to be contained in **Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNET**. I've queried all available classes in **root\cimv2** on my Win 2003/IIS6 servers, and it's not listed.

It is, however, available on an unrelated Win2008/IIS7 box (which is interesting but doesn't really help me much). I can view these counters in PerfMon without any issues.

What gives? Why is this WMI class not available on my Windows 2003 servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following registry keys and ensure "Disable Performance Counters" is either not present, or set to 0:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET\Performance\Disable Performance Counters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727\Performance\Disable Performance Counters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_64\Performance\Disable Performance Counters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727\Performance\Disable Performance Counters
```

If you have a 32-bit OS, only the first two keys will be present. If you have a 64-bit OS, all 4 keys will be present.

Comment: Great suggestion but I have tried both zero'ing those keys and deleting them altogether with no result. Also I

Comment: Does the performance counter show up in perfmon?

Comment: Yes, all ASP.NET and ASP.NETv2 counters are available in perfmon.

Comment: I would recommend the wmi diagnosis utility for win2003: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d7ba3cd6-18d1-4d05-b11e-4c64192ae97d

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent msdn blog article which helped me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/11/asp-net-performance-counters-missing.aspx